# CellID location with CDMA

Tags: android, location, cellid, cdma

Is there a way to determine location via CellID on a CDMA network? I can get a network ID, base station ID, and system ID programatically, but is there an api somewhere to convert these to lat, long coordinates? The CdmaCellLocation.getBaseStationLatitude() and CdmaCellLocation.getBaseStationLongitude() methods return some junk number. Can I convert the cdma dating I'm getting to CID and LAC somehow?

I'm getting a system ID of 40, a network ID of 3, and a base station ID of 4672, and that appears to be exactly worthless.

Comment: Why not use `LocationManager` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`?

Comment: Since API level 5 the CdmaCellLocation class has two methods for this (public int getBaseStationLatitude ()....), but in my testing they always return the invalid result (Integer.MAX).  The fact they are defined as returning int suggests to me they are "not serious".... With GsmLocation you can look up location using a Google Maps API, but don't know what to do on CDMA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interrelate googleEarth with your system to interpret
the CELLID and LAC into Longitude and Latitute.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two years later but it is not a problem, maybe someone is going to profit from the answer. [Here](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/create-simple-cell-id-look-application-android) is a code in which they do what you want, even thou they are using the Ericsson API limited to 500 requests per day. There is another one [here](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html) that uses a Google API that is not working anymore, but it is nice to have the rest of the code as a reference, and also a discussion about it.

Nowadays, if I was going to program such a application, I would use a combination of services like OpenCellID, OpenBmap, and FireEagle. Why Combination? Because some of them contain information of towers for some countries, and few, or not even one for another. You can check their API, respectively [here](http://www.opencellid.org/api), [here](http://openbmap.org/api/openbmap_api.php5), and [here](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/developer/explorer) and use a code similar to those linked to consult it.

As final remarks, [this](http://www.developergarden.com/apis/blog-events/blog/articles/article/cell-phone-localization-using-cell-ids/) site presents a nice and descriptive table with services that provide location based on cell information. Some are off, but you should take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Cell Towers database from [opencellid.org](http://opencellid.org) . It is a table that it's columns is `Cell id` , `MCC` , `MNC` , `Latitude` , `Logitude` and etc . You can Lookup your position of BTS using it's `cell id` .